# Linq deferred execution with local values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I've been experimenting with Linq to see what it can do - and I'm really loving it so far :)

I wrote some queries for an algorithm, but I didn't get the results I expected... the Enumeration always returned empty:

**case #1**

```
List<some_object> next = new List<some_object>();
some_object current = null;

var valid_next_links =
    from candidate in next
    where (current.toTime + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) <= candidate.fromTime)
    orderby candidate.fromTime
    select candidate;

current = something;
next = some_list_of_things;

foreach (some_object l in valid_next_links)
{
    //do stuff with l
}
```

I changed the query declaration to be inline like this, and it worked fine:

**case #2**

```
 foreach (some_object l in
      (from candidate in next
       where (current.toTime + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) <= candidate.fromTime)
       orderby candidate.fromTime
       select candidate))
 {
  //do stuff with l
 }
```

Does anybody know why it doesn't work in case #1 ?
The way I understood it, the query wasn't evaluated when you declared it, so I don't see how there is a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changes to `current` will be captured, but the query already knows the *value* of `next`. Adding extra items to the existing list will make them show up in the query, but changing the value of the variable to refer to a different list entirely won't have any effect. Basically, if you mentally expand the query from a query expression into a "normal" form, any variable present in a lambda expression will be captured as a variable, but any variable present directly as an argument will be evaluated immediately. That will only capture the *reference* value of the variable, not the items present in the list, but it still means changing the variable value itself won't be seen. Your first query expands to:

```
var valid_next_links = next
      .Where(candidate => (current.toTime + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) <= candidate.fromTime))
      .OrderBy(candidate => candidate.fromTime);
```